# Heroku Database Settings Injection - How do I setup my dev django database?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to get my local dev django app to work after following these instructions on adding env database settings.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-injection

I followed the instructions but get the following error when my app tries to access the local database

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.
```

My database settings originally,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'foo',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'bar',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

the heroku article says to add the following to the settings file

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

how do I get dj_database_url.config to use my my dev settings when the DATABASE_URL is not available in dev?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can just add your dev settings to the default values like this...

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://foo:bar@localhost:5432/db')}
```

Comment: How does this set the engine, which appears to be necessary at least for the local environment?

Comment: If you take a look at the `dj_database_url.config` method you'll see that the ENGINE value is derived from the scheme of the database URL ie `postgres://`

Comment: It's better if you define the DATABASE_URL in an environment variable, which config() will read.

Answer (score 13):

Use this in your settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])}
```

and in your .env file have this:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/yourdbname
```

when you launch with "foreman start" it will look at the .env file and create all those environment variables, just like running on Heroku itself.  Type "heroku config" to confirm that you have a DATABASE_URL set, which you should if you added the postgres database addon.

Comment: It's redundant to assign 'default' to DATABASE_URL, which is the environment variable that config() reads...by default.

Answer (score 8):

Just set an environment variable on your operating system and check weither or not it's set. For instance, with a UNIX system:

```
# In ~/.bash_profile
export LOCAL_DEV=true

# In settings.py
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

if bool(os.environ.get('LOCAL_DEV', False)):
    # Override DATABASES['default'] with your local database configuration
```

Also, if you need to [set an environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) on your heroku space:

```
heroku config:add MY_VAR='my_value'
```

Comment: Actually the correct syntax is `heroku config:add MY_VAR='my_value'`

Comment: heroku config:set MY_VAR='value' is okay too. add is an alias :)

Answer (score 5):

I just tried this and here is my code:

```
import dj_database_url

local_db = 'postgres://django_login:123456@localhost/django_db'
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=local_db)}
```

My database name is "django_db", user name is "django_login", password is "123456".

My code can run both in local machine and heroku.

Answer (score 1):

> import dj_database_url
>
> DATABASES = {'default':
>   dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://**yourusername**:**yourpassword**@**yourhosturl**:5432/**yourdbname**')}

** Replace bold string with your database settings
if you are using local database then replace *yourhosturl* by *localhost*