# Heroku+django: cannot find config vars locally

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying django on heroku, following the [official tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#syncing_the_database) and stuck at the `creating celery and kombu tables locally` step using `python manage.py syncdb`, getting following errors:

> File "/my/virtual/path/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py",
>   line 162, in _cursor
>   raise ImproperlyConfigured("You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.") 
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.

The problem is it cannot find the db I set for heroku by the config vars of heroku. When I run `heroku config`, it displays the `DATABASE_URL` of my app correctly, but when I try:

> if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ

in python interpreter, it returns `false`. I also check, none of my config vars is in my `os.environ`. Shouldn't vars be added to it automatically? My previous steps are correct.

I searched and got a lot of solutions to detect the heroku db but they all are based on the assumption that I have the `DATABASE_URL` in my `os.environ`.

Could anyone point out where I went wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See this page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071579/heroku-database-settings-injection-how-do-i-setup-my-dev-django-database



it work, ldiqual's answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the tutorial is missing some steps on how to run the app locally. If you want to sync the database locally, you should override the "default" DATABASE with the one you have on your machine. There is one similar answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072426/59352) with code sample.

Comment: I tried the code it still does not work. Now when I run `syncdb` it says `image not found` error.

Comment: Hey I finally get the code you mentioned working. It turns out I misconfigured my postgresql. you are right, heroku itself seems not to consider the local env. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

visit this page

[Heroku Database Settings Injection - How do I setup my dev django database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071579/heroku-database-settings-injection-how-do-i-setup-my-dev-django-database)

*ldiqual*'s answer is right.